# Flexible Column Layout, column spaning functionality

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am creating an App based on the Flexible Column Layout. I've got 2 Buttons which don't belong to a single column, but all. (general user settings & help)
The solution I am using at the moment is a putting the Flexible Column Layout inside a page and then putting the buttons into the the headerContent.

My Question:

In consideration of the FIORI - Designguidelines, is there a better way to do that? 
In the Guidelines them self this scenario isn't marked as a no go, but i don't think it was intended to be done. So I figured maybe the community can give me some insights.

Example Code:

```
<View xmlns="sap.f"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:m="sap.m"
    displayBlock="true"
    controllerName="wui.bds.controller.FlexColLayout"
    height="100%">
    <m:Page>
        <m:headerContent>
            <m:Button
                icon="sap-icon://user-settings"
                text="{i18n>persSetButton}"
                type="Transparent"
                press="onPersSetButton"/>
            <m:Button
                icon="sap-icon://sys-help"
                text="{i18n>helpButton}"
                type="Transparent"
                press="onHelpButton"/>
        </m:headerContent>



        <FlexibleColumnLayout id="fcl"
                            busy="{appView>/busy}"
                            busyIndicatorDelay="{appView>/delay}"
                            stateChange="onStateChanged"
                            layout="{/layout}"
                            backgroundDesign="Solid"></FlexibleColumnLayout>
    </m:Page>
</View>
```

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Update: Example Pic: 
(The press me Button will be removed once I create a mock data service or an Odate one)
[image: Flexible Column Layout with headerContent of the page]

Comment: Can you also add an image here for more understanding?

Comment: As it seems like you are trying to create a set of buttons which do not belong to flexible column layout, could you read through the floorplan here https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/

Comment: Have you considered a shell plugin, or consider that something like settings might be part of the 'master' list? I think that's how page wide buttons are handled in the master-detail page.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi thanks for your thoughts. I already read through the floorplan but there is not descriped how to handle Buttons which are to be available throughout all columns

Comment: @Jorg thanks for your reply. I too considered to put the help button inside the 'master' column, but it seemed kind of strange that, if you wanted to access the help while having the middle column expanded u'd first need to switch column. That does not seem right to me. Duplicating the button would be possible too, but then you'd see it double when your in 2 column view...

Comment: can you please also share what are these global buttons for? As in dont they belong anywhere else in the app, as per design guidelines?

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi the help button is supposed to open a new tab with the user documentation, explaining how the app works etc. to decrease hotline calls, the settings button handles settings like reminders, substitute workers, etc.

Comment: This should be placed in the master page of your application or to be linked with an element (if any)which is related to the app.